# Cutting and pasting range of cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to cut and paste a range of cells in a single worksheet using VBA. I have the range in a variable. So for Example I want to cut Cells `C1:C40` where `"C1:C40"` is stored in a var called `WorkRangeVar`. I want to cut this range to before the first column which should be `A1`. Here is the code I am using. Everything works fine except setting the `WorkRange` range object.

```
colNumber = WorksheetFunction.Match("What", TmpRng, 0)
ConvertToLetter = ""

columnToLetter (colNumber)
WorkRngVar = ConvertToLetter & "1:" & (ConvertToLetter) & LastRow
Range(WorkRngVar).Copy
Set WorkRange = Range(WorkRngVar)
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Why do you need the `WorkRange` variable? It doesn't appear that you're even using it.

Comment: shouldn't `columnToLetter` be part of `WorkRngVar`? (BTW: you can use numbers rather than letters to refer to ranges if you use the `Cells` property)

Comment: Isn't your `convertToLetter`, which you use to set the `WorkRngVar`, going to be blank? So the `WorkRngVar` will just be something like `1:A10` instead of `A1:A10` or whatever?  Should that be `columnToLetter & "1:" & (ConverttoLetter) & LastRow`?

Comment: Just got it to work. Variable was being set with incorrect column name.

Comment: Which variable was it?

Comment: Bruce, it was WorkRngVar

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you could just use Cells and use the number you already picked up:

```
colNumber = WorksheetFunction.Match("What", TmpRng, 0)

Range(cells(1, colnumber), cells(LastRow, colnumber)).Copy
Set WorkRange = Range(cells(1, colnumber), cells(LastRow, colnumber))
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```